# Mosquitto >1.5 User Access Level Wildcard

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to use Mosquitto MQTT Broker v1.5.8. 
I am using mosquitto_auth_plugin for User Authentication. (https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug)

I created a mysql server with users and acls tables. 
I want to setup a user that can subscribe to topic `test/#`. 
So I setup the rw = 5 in the acls table for that user
However the user is not able to subscribe to any `test/#` but can subscribe to `test/123`

I looked at one of the issue posted https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug/issues/356
but since the Repo is archived, I cant ask questions there.

```
mysql> select * from acls;
+----+--------------+--------------------+----+
| id | username     | topic              | rw |
+----+--------------+--------------------+----+
|  1 | test         | test/#             |  5 |
+----+--------------+--------------------+----+
```

Comment: Edit the question to show everything that is in the ACL table for that user

Comment: I have added the acls table

Comment: Have you made the query changes suggested in the issue you point to?

Comment: Yes, this is my current query
```auth_opt_aclquery SELECT topic FROM acls WHERE (username = '%s') AND (rw & %d) AND ( NOT (topic REGEXP '[+#]') OR (rw & 3) )```